# Problem with examining convergence of series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences

Examine the convergence of the following series:

$$ a) \qquad \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}  \Bigg(\frac{k^2+1}{(k+1)^2}\Bigg)^2 ; $$

$$ b) \qquad \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{2^k}{\lfloor\frac{k}{2}\rfloor!} $$

In part b), the floor function $ \lfloor a \rfloor$ function returns the largest integer less than or equal to a given number.

As I'm really stuck on these two, can you give me any ideas/solutions/hints?

Comment: In the first series the limit of the sequence of terms is not $0,$ so that settles that almost instantly.

Comment: the second one is convergent by ratio test.

Answer (score 1):

The first series is not convergent since the general term tends to 1 in infinity.
For the second one, put $U_k:=\frac{2^k}{[k/2]}.$
We have $$\lim_{k\to \infty} \frac{U_{k+1}}{U_k}= \lim_{k\to \infty} \frac{2}{[(k+1)/2]}=0<1$$ then by d'Alembet criterion,
 we get the convergence of the second series.
(for the d'Alembert criterion, see https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%A8gle_de_d'Alembert)

Comment: How did you simplify the integer parts.